# How to remove a Dyno on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, resque, dyno

Following is what about dashboard says regarding Dynos:

[image]

For the time being, I only need two dynos: **web** & **resque**, and I do not need the third one: **worker**. How can I get rid of it, or is it something default by Heroku, and I'm not allowed to remove it.

If I can't remove it, is there a way that what I'm doing on **resque** dyno, can I get the same results through **woker** dyno?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `worker` dyno type is likely being provided by your buildpack. See the output of your deployment:

```
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> clock, sidekiq, web
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, worker
```

I believe you would have to change what buildpack you are using to remove the `worker` dyno type.

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the line that starts with "worker" in your Procfile, and do a "git push heroku master".

Comment: I have only one line in my `Procfile` that says: `esque: env TERM_CHILD=1 RESQUE_TERM_TIMEOUT=7 QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work`, and nothing else I have added to this file.